# Create a Library Variable in Azure Devops

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have a release that creates a load balancer in my cloud environment. I would like to run that release, grab the load balancer ARN, and add it to Azure Devops (VSTS) library variable group. This way, other releases that will add services on that load balancer can reference that variable.

Is it possible to create/update a library variable from a release?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible using the rest-api (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/distributedtask/variablegroups/update?view=vsts-rest-5.0). 
In your release you can enable 'Allow scripts to use OAuth token' on the agent-phase and use that token to authenticate your calls.

It may also be possible using the client-assemblies (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/concepts/dotnet-client-libraries?view=vsts) but i haven't checked that out yet...